# R - How to replace NA with condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

[image]

I have a dataframe like the above. it has `college`, `sub_college`, `dept`, `abbr`. but some values are missing. I want to replace the `NA` by rows with the same `abbr`.

For example, I want all rows with `abbr = ATM S` to have:

```
college name = college of the enviroment
sub_college = collge on the enviorment
dept = atmospheric sciences
```

Dput

```
    structure(list(year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L), term = c("Autumn", 
"Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", 
"Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", 
"Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", 
"Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", 
"Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", 
"Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", 
"Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn"
), college_text = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), sub_college_text = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    department_text = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), dept_abbrev = c("A A", 
    "A A", "A A", "A A", "A A", "A A", "A A", "A A", "A A", "A A", 
    "A A", "A A", "A A", "A A", "A S", "A S", "A S", "A S", "A S", 
    "A S", "A S", "AAS", "AAS", "AAS", "AAS", "AAS", "AAS", "ACADEM", 
    "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", 
    "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", 
    "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", "ACCTG", 
    "ACCTG"), course_no = c(198L, 210L, 310L, 311L, 320L, 402L, 
    405L, 430L, 447L, 461L, 501L, 503L, 516L, 530L, 101L, 101L, 
    101L, 211L, 331L, 331L, 431L, 101L, 330L, 360L, 370L, 385L, 
    395L, 197L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 225L, 301L, 301L, 301L, 302L, 
    303L, 303L, 311L, 320L, 320L, 321L, 321L, 411L, 440L, 485L, 
    500L, 500L, 506L, 521L), section_id = c("A  ", "A  ", "A  ", 
    "A  ", "A  ", "A  ", "A  ", "A  ", "A  ", "A  ", "A  ", "A  ", 
    "A  ", "B  ", "A  ", "B  ", "C  ", "A  ", "A  ", "B  ", "A  ", 
    "A  ", "A  ", "A  ", "A  ", "A  ", "A  ", "A  ", "A  ", "B  ", 
    "C  ", "A  ", "A  ", "B  ", "C  ", "A  ", "A  ", "B  ", "A  ", 
    "A  ", "B  ", "A  ", "B  ", "A  ", "A  ", "A  ", "C  ", "D  ", 
    "A  ", "A  "), course_code = c("A A 198 A", "A A 210 A", 
    "A A 310 A", "A A 311 A", "A A 320 A", "A A 402 A", "A A 405 A", 
    "A A 430 A", "A A 447 A", "A A 461 A", "A A 501 A", "A A 503 A", 
    "A A 516 A", "A A 530 B", "A S 101 A", "A S 101 B", "A S 101 C", 
    "A S 211 A", "A S 331 A", "A S 331 B", "A S 431 A", "AAS 101 A", 
    "AAS 330 A", "AAS 360 A", "AAS 370 A", "AAS 385 A", "AAS 395 A", 
    "ACADEM 197 A", "ACCTG 215 A", "ACCTG 215 B", "ACCTG 215 C", 
    "ACCTG 225 A", "ACCTG 301 A", "ACCTG 301 B", "ACCTG 301 C", 
    "ACCTG 302 A", "ACCTG 303 A", "ACCTG 303 B", "ACCTG 311 A", 
    "ACCTG 320 A", "ACCTG 320 B", "ACCTG 321 A", "ACCTG 321 B", 
    "ACCTG 411 A", "ACCTG 440 A", "ACCTG 485 A", "ACCTG 500 C", 
    "ACCTG 500 D", "ACCTG 506 A", "ACCTG 521 A"), course_title = c("SPECIAL TOPICS", 
    "ENGR STATICS", "ORB SPACE FLIGHT", "ATM FLIGHT MECH", "AEROSPACE INSTR", 
    "FLUID MECHANICS", "AEROSPACE PLASMAS", "FINTE ELEMENT ANALYS", 
    "CONT IN AEROSP", "ADVANCED PROPULSION", "PHYS GASDYNMCS I", 
    "CONTINUUM MECH", "STAB & CON FLT VEH", "MECHANICS OF SOLIDS", 
    "FOUNDATION USAF I", "FOUNDATION USAF I", "FOUNDATION USAF I", 
    "AIR & SPACE PWR I", "AEROSPACE STDYS 300", "AEROSPACE STDYS 300", 
    "AEROSPACE STDYS 400", "ASIAN-AM CULTURE", "ASIAN AMER THEATER", 
    "FIL-AM HIST & CLTR", "JPN-AM HIST CLTR", "AAS LAW AND IMMIGRA", 
    "SE-ASIAN AM HST/CLT", "RESEARCH SEMINARS", "ACCTG & FIN REPRTNG", 
    "ACCTG & FIN REPRTNG", "ACCTG & FIN REPRTNG", "MANAGERIAL ACCTG", 
    "INTERMED ACCTG I", "INTERMED ACCTG I", "INTERMED ACCTG I", 
    "INTERMED ACCTG II", "INTERMED ACCTG III", "INTERMED ACCTG III", 
    "COST ACCOUNTING", "ACCTG INFO SYSTEMS", "ACCTG INFO SYSTEMS", 
    "TAX EFF OF BUS DECS", "TAX EFF OF BUS DECS", "AUDIT STANDRDS PRIN", 
    "ACC & FIN MGT DEC", "ADV FIN ACCTG", "FINANCIAL ACCTG", 
    "FINANCIAL ACCTG", "INTEN ACCT PRIN 1", "CASES INFO QUALITY"
    ), credits = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), student_count = c("25", "186", 
    "57", "57", "57", "19", "28", "24", "47", "29", "24", "17", 
    "15", "21", "21", "15", "20", "18", "22", "18", "25", "97", 
    "40", "44", "35", "40", "27", "36", "195", "194", "179", 
    "178", "57", "59", "53", "45", "44", "54", "54", "50", "15", 
    "56", "34", "36", "28", "39", "56", "55", "59", "47"), A = c("22", 
    "21", "7", "8", "3", "1", "4", "3", "10", "2", "10", "1", 
    "6", "NULL", "6", "7", "15", "13", "11", "12", "4", "NULL", 
    "6", "10", "4", "3", "4", "7", "25", "33", "14", "5", "3", 
    "NULL", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "8", "1", "4", "4", "2", 
    "3", "4", "4", "3", "2", "17"), Aminus = c("3", "30", "13", 
    "15", "19", "7", "4", "8", "14", "10", "12", "4", "3", "5", 
    "6", "3", "2", "1", "6", "4", "5", "14", "23", "13", "9", 
    "19", "9", "18", "36", "33", "42", "51", "11", "15", "13", 
    "13", "14", "15", "11", "19", "4", "27", "11", "15", "8", 
    "10", "28", "33", "26", "30"), Bplus = c("NULL", "40", "15", 
    "11", "19", "6", "5", "7", "11", "8", "1", "7", "2", "4", 
    "2", "NULL", "NULL", "2", "4", "1", "7", "30", "7", "6", 
    "3", "12", "3", "9", "21", "24", "25", "15", "12", "22", 
    "12", "5", "13", "7", "35", "9", "6", "13", "7", "10", "10", 
    "7", "17", "16", "15", "NULL"), B = c("NULL", "30", "10", 
    "14", "13", "3", "8", "4", "6", "5", "NULL", "4", "4", "2", 
    "3", "1", "2", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "3", "28", "2", "4", 
    "6", "6", "5", "2", "27", "30", "35", "29", "11", "10", "15", 
    "10", "6", "10", "4", "6", "2", "4", "9", "7", "4", "3", 
    "7", "3", "12", "NULL"), Bminus = c("NULL", "31", "8", "6", 
    "3", "1", "1", "2", "4", "2", "NULL", "1", "NULL", "7", "1", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "1", "NULL", "4", "16", "1", "5", 
    "7", "NULL", "2", "NULL", "22", "23", "22", "45", "11", "6", 
    "4", "10", "5", "10", "1", "4", "2", "4", "1", "2", "3", 
    "7", "NULL", "NULL", "2", "NULL"), Cplus = c("NULL", "14", 
    "2", "2", "NULL", "1", "3", "NULL", "1", "2", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "1", "NULL", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "1", "4", "NULL", "1", "4", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "9", 
    "12", "15", "7", "6", "3", "2", "NULL", "2", "5", "NULL", 
    "2", "NULL", "3", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "3", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL"), C = c("NULL", "9", "2", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "1", "NULL", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "1", "NULL", "1", 
    "NULL", "1", "2", "NULL", "2", "NULL", "12", "11", "7", "12", 
    "NULL", "1", "2", "2", "1", "4", "NULL", "2", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "3", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"
    ), Cminus = c("NULL", "4", "NULL", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "2", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "2", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "23", "12", "6", "2", 
    "NULL", "2", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL"), Dplus = c("NULL", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "2", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"), D = c("NULL", "1", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "11", "7", "NULL", "2", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"), 
    Dminus = c("NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "1", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "3", 
    "NULL", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"), Fail = c("NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "2", "1", "NULL", "1", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "2", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "3", "1", "1", "2", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "1", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"), W = c("NULL", 
    "5", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "1", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "1", "1", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "1", "2", "NULL", "2", "NULL", "NULL", "2", 
    "NULL", "6", "5", "12", "5", "2", "NULL", "NULL", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "1", "1", "NULL", "NULL", "1", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "2", "NULL"), avg_gpa = c(3.9, 3, 3.2, 3.2, 
    3.3, 3.3, 3.1, 3.4, 3.4, 3.3, 3.7, 3.3, 3.5, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 
    3.8, 3.6, 3.7, 3.7, 3.2, 3, 3.4, 3.3, 3, 3.4, 3.3, 3.6, 2.8, 
    2.9, 3, 2.9, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.4, 
    3.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3, 3.4, 3.4, 3.3, 3.7), professor_rating = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), no_responses = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), lastname = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), firstname = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have no clue how to make that happen.
Appreciate your help!

Comment: please provide the code to generate a sample of the data frame to ease the community to help you, you could use `dput`

Comment: @DavidS thanks for your reply! i just included dput in my question.

Comment: For the `dput` you have shared which columns you want to replace? with which values ? What is `abbr` ?

Answer (score 1):

You didin't provide usable example, hence I wrote it without any check. I was thinking about `mutate()` from `dplyr`, but in this simple case base R should do the trick. Nevertheless correct me if I'm wrong.

```
df$college[df&abbr=='ATM S'] = "college of the enviroment"
df$sub_college[df&abbr=='ATM S'] = "collge on the enviorment"
df$dept[df&abbr=='ATM S'] = "atmospheric sciences"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is always a unique value for each column for each group, we can use `dplyr` as below.

```r
replace_fun <- function(x) {
  replace_na(x, unique(x[!is.na(x)]))
}

df %>%
  group_by(abbr) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(college, sub_college, dept), replace_fun)
```

Comment: It is actually not always having a unique value for each column for each group. Some groups might just be NA all the way, in which case I wish to leave it as it is.